# Page inside UWP SplitView control has a limit to its Width

Tags: win-universal-app

As described in this GitHub issue (https://github.com/eloekset/UWPSplitViewIssue/issues/1) I try to make an UWP calculator app that can be as tiny as the built-in calculator in Windows 10. However after adding a SplitView control to get a hamburger button and a side pane menu, the Page hosted inside the SplitView.Content cannot be any narrower than 320 pixels.

I find that odd, as the built-in calculator clearly can be as small as 202x357 pixels, while it also has a hamburger button and a side pane menu. I assume it is built using the same SplitView control as all UWP apps have access to, so I must be doing something wrong.

[image: Original Windows 10 calculator app]
[image]

To demonstrate the problem, I've created a simple project with the same issue and published it on GitHub: https://github.com/eloekset/UWPSplitViewIssue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the window smaller by using `SetPreferredMinSize` in the app's OnLaunched method.

Here is an example

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
...
     var applicationView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
     applicationView.SetPreferredMinSize(new Size { Width = 202, Height = 357 });

    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

The smallest allowed size is 192x48 EP (Effective Pixels). [See here for more information](http://The%20smallest%20allowed%20minimum%20size%20is%20192%20x%2048%20effective%20pixels).

As far as the SplitView.Content region goes, I've inspected the Template and do not see anything that would restrict it's minimum size with the exception of the Pane's ColumnDefinition

Here is the snippet from the extracted SplitView Template:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1"
                                      Width="{Binding TemplateSettings.OpenPaneGridLength, FallbackValue=0, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition2"
                                      Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I notice the `ColumnDefinition1` that is using Binding `TemplateSettings.OpenPaneLength`, after testing `OpenPaneLength="0"` it seems to respect the content.

Here is the debug output I got using your GitHub repo after setting OpenPaneLength to 0

```
Page Width: 202 and Height: 464
ContentFrame Width: 202 and Height: 464
Smallest there is.
```